# Object [object Object] has no method 'query' sails

Tags: mysql, sails.js

Trying to execute a query in sails.Code is given below:

```
Question.query("Select id from question", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return "Hello";
  }else {
          console.log("in here");
          return "world";
     }
});
```

it gives an error that object has no method 'query'.

Comment: What DB adapter are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install the sails mysql adapter `npm install sails-mysql`
and make sure that you defined the mysql db connection in `config/adapters.js` like

```
module.exports.adapters = {


 'default': 'mysql',


disk: {
    module: 'sails-disk'
  },


  mysql: {
    module: 'sails-mysql',
    user: 'dbUser',
    database: 'dbName',
    host: 'dbHost',
    password: 'dbPassword'
  }
};
```